# Play Store not registering my phone after root

Tags: google-play-store, rooting

I rooted my phone and after that for the 1st time, as I was just checking out stuff, Google Play recognized my device and registered it.

Later I did a factory reset and now for some reason it is not registering my phone and I cannot download anything!

Entering the "My apps" section only lists the installed apps. No update options, no all apps section!

What happened? Now what should I do?

Comment: Did you re-add the same accounts?  Has it upgraded to the latest app version?  Have you tried clearing the data for the app and rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

[Update](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1836057) to latest [Play Store](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1463820&d=1352297226).

Clear Play Store app's **Data and Cache**.

Reboot your phone. They check whether problem exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just did another factory reset and its all fine now! the behavior was weird though!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because of the Freedom app.

To fix it:

1. Download Root Explorer
2. Go to `etc` then click on mount on the upper part
3. Find the `hosts` and delete it
4. Restart the phone